# config-map kubernetes multiple environments

Tags: spring-boot, deployment, kubernetes

I am trying to deploy a Spring Boot application using configuration data from Kubernetes cluster. I have a simple RestController that prints a message by reading from a Kubernetes cluster.

```
    private String message = "Message not coming from Kubernetes config map";

@RequestMapping(value="/echo", method=GET)
public String printKubeConfig() {
    return message;
}
```

Specified the name of the config map in my application.yml

```
spring:
  application:
    name: echo-configmap
```

echo-configmap

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: echo-configmap
data:
  application.properties: |-
    message=Hello from dev Kubernetes Configmap
  application_qa.properties: |-
    message=Hello from qa Kubernetes Configmap
```

I have several environments like qa, int, test etc

1. What's the best way to specify environment specific properties in the config map? And how to access them in Spring boot application?
   Ex: if the application is deployed in qa, my service should return the message "Hello from qa Kubernetes Configmap"
2. We also have plans to read these configuration files from GIT in future. How to handle that usecase?

Answer (score 9):

Let me try and provide an answer which I think gives you what you need, without using any tools beyond what you'll have installed on most boxes. Maybe try this first, and if you find the approach becomes difficult to manage and scale, move onto something more sophisticated.

### Step 1: Version control configmaps per environment

Create a folder like `k8s/configmaps` or something, and create one configmap per environment:

```
k8s/configmaps/properties.dev.yaml
k8s/configmaps/properties.qa.yaml
k8s/configmaps/properties.sit.yaml
k8s/configmaps/properties.uat.yaml
```

Each configmap should contain your environment specific settings.

### Step 2: Have a namespace per environment

Create a k8s namespace per environment, such as:

```
 application-dev
 application-qa
 application-sit
 application-uat
```

### Step 3: Create the configmap per environment

A little bash will help here:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# apply-configmaps.sh
namespace="application-${ENVIRONMENT}"
for configmap in ./k8s/configmaps/*.${ENVIRONMENT}.yml; do
    echo "Processing ConfigMap $configmap"
    kubectl apply -n ${namespace} -f $configmap
done
```

Now all you need to do to create *or update* configmaps for any environment is:

```
ENVIRONMENT=dev ./update-configmaps.sh
```

### Step 4: Finish the job with CI/CD

Now you can create a CI/CD pipeline - if your configmap source changes just run the command shown above.

### Summary

Based on primitive commands and no special tools you can:

- Version control config
- Manage config per environment
- Update or create config when the config code changes
- Easily apply the same approach in a CI/CD pipeline if needed

I would strongly recommend you follow this basic 'first principles' approach before jumping into more sophisticated tools to solve the same problems, in many cases you can do it yourself without much effort, learn the key concepts and save the more sophisticated tooling till later if you really need it.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion!! Spring boot application takes only the name of a config map.  we can pass this parameter as a command line argument to the application? Any other suggestions?                                                                                                                                      `spring:
  application:
    name: echo-configmap`

Comment: Sorry @AV how do you mean? Normally if you have a config map you would simply have it mount its values as a set of environment variables directly to the application process, or have the config map mounted into the container filesystem, so that your app can load it from (for example) '/etc/myapp/config' or whatever - that would be something like this : https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/#populate-a-volume-with-data-stored-in-a-configmap

Comment: A follow up question on this. If there are properties that are same across all the environments and we don't want to repeat them in each config-map, how can we place those common properties?

Comment: @AV probably just create a single config map called 'shared' and mount the values from that into each container

Comment: Hi @DaveKerr: I am also facing the same issue. I am not using helm. I have mutliple profiles in single config map (as mentioned in this question). But the spring boot app is picking up the values only from the application.properties even though I activated some other profile. Any clue over here? Thx in advance.

Answer (score 8):

This sounds like a good use case for [Helm](https://helm.sh). You could deploy your application as a [Helm Chart](https://docs.helm.sh/developing_charts), which would basically allow you to generate your Kubernetes resources (like ConfigMaps, Deployments, and whatever else you need) from templates.

You can use [the documentation on Helm Charts](https://docs.helm.sh/developing_charts/) to get started with Helm. After having created a Chart with [`helm create`](https://docs.helm.sh/helm/#helm-create), you will get a `templates/` directory, in which you might place the following YAML template for your ConfigMap:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: {{ printf "%s-%s" .Release.Name .Chart.Name }}
  labels:
    app: {{ .Chart.Name | trunc 63 | trimSuffix "-" }}
    chart: {{ .Chart.Name }}-{{ .Chart.Version | replace "+" "_" }}
    release: {{ .Release.Name }}
    heritage: {{ .Release.Service }}
data:
  application.properties: |-
    message={{ .Values.properties.message }}
```

You can add a second YAML template for your Deployment object (actually, `helm create` will already create a sensible default deployment). Simply add your ConfigMap as volume, there:

```
containers:
  - name: {{ .Chart.Name }}
    # [...]
    volumes:
      - name: property-volume
        mountPath: /etc/your-app/properties
volumes:
  - name: property-volume
    configMap:
      name: {{ printf "%s-%s" .Release.Name .Chart.Name }}
```

Each Helm chart has a `values.yaml` file, in which you can define default values that are then used to fill in your templates. This default file might look like this (remember that the ConfigMap template above contained a `{{ .Values.properties.message }}` expression):

```
replicaCount: 1
image:
  repository: your-docker-image
  tag: your-docker-tag
properties:
  message: Hello!
```

Next, use this Helm chart and the [`helm install` command](https://docs.helm.sh/helm/#helm-install) to deploy your application as many times as you want with different configurations. You can supply different YAML files in which you override specific values from your `values.yaml` file, or override individual values using `--set`:

```
$ helm install --name dev --set image.tag=latest --set replicaCount=1 path/to/chart
$ helm install --name prod --set image.tag=stable --set replicaCount=3 --set properties.message="Hello from prod" path/to/chart
```

As to your second question: Of course you should put your Helm Chart into version control. You can then use the [`helm upgrade` command](https://docs.helm.sh/helm/#helm-upgrade) to apply changes to an already deployed application.

Comment: Thanks for your response. We are trying to stick to the basic Kubernetes concepts and see how they work out. Helm sounds like a great idea. We need to do a prototype.

Answer (score 2):

I would use this tool for each of your git projects for non secret data.
https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kustomize

In the meta data you can filter your pods

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: mycomponent
    env: dev
    tier: backend
  name: mycomponent
  namespace: myapplication
```

kubectl get pods -n myapplication -l env=dev,tier=backend,app=mycomponent

Answer (score 1):

Typically you want that applications running on `qa` don't interfere with applications running on `production`. Using Kubernetes, you can get this kind of isolation [using different namespaces for different environments](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/namespaces/).
That way, objects on the `prod` namespace are different from objects on the `qa` namespace. Another, more expensive approach would be to use different k8s clusters for different environments.

Having this setup, you would deploy your application in the namespace for the specific environment where you want to deploy to, creating the `Deployment` object on that namespace.
This `Deployment` would make use of a `ConfigMap` object containing your Spring Boot properties. Let's call this `ConfigMap` **echo-properties** for example.

That way, every namespace would have a unique copy of the **echo-properties** `ConfigMap`. Each containing the specific configuration for the environment where it belongs.

The `Deployment` object consumes the `ConfigMap` properties by either using environment variables or reading files. The important bit here is that if you change the **echo-properties** `ConfigMap` data, your application won't see those new values, by default. Kubernetes doesn't have this feature so far. You can't compare `ConfigMap`s to Spring Cloud Config, which is a dynamic configuration solution.

An approach that would get you a similar behaviour (but not quite the same) would be using the [fabric8 ConfigMap Controller](https://github.com/fabric8io/configmapcontroller) on your cluster. This controller is a process that runs on your cluster, and it would restart your application whenever the `ConfigMap` changes, so that it reads the new configuration values.

If you don't want to restart your application whenever a configuration changes, you should probably stick to Spring Cloud Config for values that will potentially change, and use `ConfigMaps` for other properties that won't change, like application name or port.

Comment: Thanks.. We are planning to use fabric8 config library https://github.com/spring-cloud-incubator/spring-cloud-kubernetes to detect changes to config maps and dynamically reload them.                                                                              Since the spring application takes the name of the configuration map in application.yml, the only question is how to change it dynamically per environment.   `spring:
  application:
    name: echo-configmap`

Comment: As explained in the answer, you can achieve that having different namespaces for different environments. Each with its own echo-configmap. Wouldn't that solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Your use case sounds very much like you should take look at `spring-cloud-config` - https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/

The config-server is an infrastructure component that serves configuration that could be located in a git repository.

A config-client application would connect to `config-server` at startup and loads the configuration applicable to the current profiles.

You could have different branches for different environments - or use profiles per environment. In your kubernetes deployment manifest you could set the profile by setting `SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE` environment variable.

Comment: We used Spring Cloud Config before and would like to switch to use Kubernetes Configmap. Any idea how we can achieve similar functionality using Kubernetes Configmap?