# how to override Angular environments.ts that is already built in Kubernetes

Tags: angular, docker, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I am deploying an Angular application to a k8s cluster using Helm. The app is Dockerized hosted by Nginx through the Nginx Docker image. I'm deploying it in a similar fashion to this https://dev.to/oneofthedevs/docker-angular-nginx-37e4.

The issue is that I have to change the Dockerfile and change the `ng build` command inside it to target the environment I would like to deploy in (e.g. `ng build --prod`) and have different `environment.ts` files inside the project. What I would like instead is to have only one `environment.ts` and be able to change its values through Helm instead i.e. through specifying an `env:` in the `Deployment` of the image e.g.

```
env:
   - name: ENVIRONMENT
     value: prd
```

and the `environment.ts` file can read this environment variable and configure itself properly. But since the app is just static files, it can't be dynamic (or maybe I'm wrong)?

There is this answer [Angular 6 + Nginx + Docker + Kubernetes: How to configure environment variables for different environments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52325574/angular-6-nginx-docker-kubernetes-how-to-configure-environment-variables), but the issue there is that the ENV is set inside the Dockerfile instead of through Helm, and so it's too early. But if I set the env var at Helm side, the `ng build` is already ran and so I can't edit the `environment.ts` anymore. Or is there a way I can edit the bundle? I'm not an Angular dev so maybe there are some Angular tricks I don't know of.

Comment: Hi aldo, 
This problem can be solved by having environment specific image right? For example: For development environment you can have image like `app:dev`, for qa env `app:qa `and for prod `app:prod`

Comment: Ah, I was hoping I could have just a generic image, and that image can be configured easily depending on the environment varibale set by Helm

Comment: You cannot change `environment.ts` after the Angular app has been build. You can however change it before you run `ng build` using other shell commands or a script.

Comment: Have you considered using configmaps with Helm? See this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47731308/3537880) to get an understanding and may point you to the right direction